# Stars next to people in Life is Strange

Tags: life-is-strange

So I was watching a Life is Strange playthrough, and this may be a trivial question, but there is a booklet with all the faces of the people you've encountered so far. I noticed that there are yellow stars next to some of these people's pictures. What do the yellow stars represent?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 8):

The player just hasn't visited/viewed those pictures. It's the same with the text messages, pictures you took, and journal entries. As soon as they are viewed/read, the star goes away.